# How to correct this diagram block?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
% We start by placing the blocks
\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
\node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {Controller};
\node [block, right of=controller, pin={[pinstyle]above:Disturbances},
node distance=3cm] (system) {System};
% We draw an edge between the controller and system block to 
% calculate the coordinate u. We need it to place the measurement block. 
\draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
\node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
\node [block, below of=system] (measurements) {Measurements};
\node [block, left of=measurements ] (sensor) {Sensor};
\draw [<-] (measurements) -- node[name=k] {$k$} (sensor);
% Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
\draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
\draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
\draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y$}(output);
\draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
\draw [->] (sensor) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Try tikz library `positioning` and `left=1cm of measurements`, which will let you adjust the distance.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `left of=measurements` by `below=of controller`.

Three minor notes:

- The `left of`, `right of` etc keys are deprecated. It is now recommended to use `left=of ...` instead of `left of=...` etc. This requires `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`. This change is more than a transposition of letters. The new positioning is more robust and flexible than the old way.
- You can write `block/.style = {...}` (as an option to `tikzpicture` or as an argument to `\tikzset`) instead of `\tikzstyle{block} = [...]`. As I understand it, the first method (that I also used below) is more in line with the current tikz conventions. The second method is a rather singular syntax not used elsewhere in tikz.
- As Zarko has noted in the comments, the node distance can be chosen differently in the x and y direction by specifying e.g. `node distance=1cm and 2cm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\tikzset
  {block/.style =
    {draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em},
   sum/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=1cm},
   input/.style = {coordinate},
   output/.style = {coordinate},
   pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}}
  }

\begin{document}
% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm and 2cm,>=latex']
% We start by placing the blocks
\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [sum, right=of input] (sum) {};
\node [block, right=of sum] (controller) {Controller};
\node [block, right=of controller, pin={[pinstyle]above:Disturbances},
node distance=3cm] (system) {System};
% We draw an edge between the controller and system block to 
% calculate the coordinate u. We need it to place the measurement block. 
\draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
\node [output, right=of system] (output) {};
\node [block, below=of system] (measurements) {Measurements};
\node [block, below=of controller] (sensor) {Sensor};
\draw [<-] (measurements) -- node[name=k] {$k$} (sensor);
% Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
\draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
\draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
\draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y$}(output);
\draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
\draw [->] (sensor) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: probably is right `\draw [->]  (measurements) -- node[name=k] {$k$} (sensor);` :) and for node distance I would make different vertical and horizontal distance, for example `node distance=1cm and 2cm` ...

Comment: @Zarko Changing the node distance is a good idea. Regarding the arrow: My first idea was also to change its direction, but I think the arrows are correct as they are, since sensors usually only deliver data, but do not receive them.

Comment: well observation, but this means that (as far s know from control theory)  that sensor and measurement block had to be interchanged ...

Comment: @ Well, our task is to help with TeX problems ;-)

Comment: You have right :). See my answer below as supplement to yours

Answer (score 2):

As supplement to *gernot* (no so much) "verbose" answer, hopefully it is more concise :) In it I use `calc` and `quotes` library:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, positioning, quotes}
\tikzset{
     block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em},
       sum/.style = {circle, draw, fill=blue!20},
 every pin/.style = {pin edge={<-,black}},
                > = latex'
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
    node distance = 6mm and 12mm]
% placing the blocks
\coordinate (in);
\node (sum)             [sum, right=of in] {};
\node (controller)      [block, right=of sum]           {Controller};
\node (system)          [block, pin=above:Disturbances, 
                         right=of controller]           {System};
\coordinate[right=of system] (out);
\node (measurement)     [block, below=of controller]    {Measurements};
\node (sensor)          [block, below=of system]        {Sensor};
% edges between blocks
\draw[->]   (in)            edge ["$r$"] (sum)
            (sum)           edge ["$e$"] (controller)
            (controller)    edge["$u$"]  (system)
            (system)        edge["$y$"]  (out)
            (sensor)        edge["$k$"] (measurement)
            (measurement)   -|  (sum)
                            node [pos=0.75] {$y_m$}
                            node [pos=0.95] {$-$};
\draw[->]   ($(system.east)!0.5!(out)$) |- (sensor);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Change considering *CarLaTeX* comment, comments in code are now more meaningful. I still believe, that my suggested order of blocks "sensor"and "measuremnt" are correct. However until these blocks are linear, the order is not esential :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX, as *Gernot" said, we help to solve LaTeX issues :). Order become important when blocks are not linear. Hopefully OP know, what is correct to her/him and that change of blocks name after received three answers is not problem (anymore) :)

Comment: Yes, of course! It's trivial to change the position of the node... I wrote it only because I was already writing about the arrow :):):) This OP is lucky with 3 answers!

Answer (score 2):

I think you could also use a TikZ `matrix`.

Please note that `arrows` library is deprecated. From the TikZ & PGF Manual, para. 16.1:

> Remark: The libraries arrows and arrows.spaced are deprecated. Use
>   arrows.meta instead/additionally, which allows you to do all that the
>   old libraries offered, plus much more. However, the old libraries
>   still work and you can even mix old and new arrow tips (only, the old
>   arrow tips cannot be configured in the ways described in the rest of
>   this section; saying scale=2 for a latex arrow has no effect for
>   instance, while for Latex arrows it doubles their size as one would
>   expect.)

Moreover, as gernot already said, `\tikzset` should be used instead of `\tikzstyle` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/101651)).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    block/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, text width=7em,align=center},
    sum/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, circle},
    pinstyle/.style={pin edge={latex-,thin,black}},
    mylabup/.style={midway,above},
    >=latex,
    }   
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=3em, row sep=4ex]{%
    \coordinate (input);
    &
    \node [sum] (sum) {};
    &
    \node [block] (controller) {Controller};
    &
    \node [block, pin={[pinstyle]above:Disturbances}] (system) {System};
    &
    \coordinate (output);
\\
    &
    &
    \node [block] (sensor) {Sensor};
    &
    \node [block] (measurements) {Measurements};
    \\
    };
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[mylabup] {$u$} (system);
    \draw [->] (measurements) -- node[mylabup] {$k$} (sensor);
    \draw [->] (input) -- node[mylabup] {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node[mylabup] {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y,mylabup] {$y$} (output);
    \draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
    \draw [->] (sensor) -| 
node [near end, left] {$y_m$} (sum);

\node[below left = -2pt and -1pt of sum] {$-$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]